# Reloading onla a section of website using html/php

Tags: php, html, reload

I want to make a div class="test" that would be updated every 40 seconds without reloading the whole site **with PHP/HTML**. This reloads whole page `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="40" >` If anyone has a solution without js ajax it would be nice.

Comment: do you tried putting the content that you want to be refreshed inside a iframe? (with the meta tag that you posted)

Comment: Updated with what - fresh page content from the server? Why are you trying to avoid ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a HTML file example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="40" >
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    "your Div content here"
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And add this where you want that content to be refreshed on main html's div:

```
<iframe src="example.html"></iframe>
```